# Cassandra No host exception and Unable to connect to any servers

Tags: c#, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

we have a 12 node cassandra cluster spread across 2 datacenter with 6 node in each datacenter. When trying to login to cqlsh it is giving below error for most of the nodes and just allowing login one node:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'<server_IP>': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection (5 seconds), last_host=None',)})
```

The only difference that i see is the node on which it is working doesn't have blocked request for Native-Transport-Requests. Could this be the issue? Here is the tpstats output from one of the node where it is not working.

We also have 2 net application running, one which reads data from cassandra other that writes to it. We are also seeing this .net application frequently closing with **Cassandra No host exception**. Is this due to the same reason?
[image]

Comment: most probably some of the queries are very long running and there by piling up the new requests - couple of things to check and confirm,
1. try increasing the max_queued_native_transport_requests.
2. Look into the slow running queries - may be you will find the root cause there and can fix that - something like an aggregate query or a query which scans all partitions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error after upgrading my cassandra cluster. I saw @Parth Gandhi's post about blocked native transports and realized that we had set native_transport_max_threads to zero, thinking it would set it to unlimited. There were actually no errors in the logs about it so it was quite strange. Once I commented out the parameter from the cassandra.yaml for native_transport_max_threads and bounced the node, I could again finally connect to the cluster.